# each textbox validation in script

Tags: javascript

This is my script, I want to create alert when field is empty then display the alert on screen when enter key is pressed. I want the script which including when I write in the textbox and press enter then verify that keyword and go to next textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
 if( document.myForm.vname.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Vehicle Name!" );
     document.myForm.vname.focus();
     return false;
   }
else if (document.myForm.vname.value.length > 15)
    {
        alert("Vehicle name cannot be more than 15 characters");
        document.myForm.vname.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
else if(!document.myForm.vname.value.match(letters))
  {
  alert("Enter Only Characters ");
  document.myForm.vname.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
 if( document.myForm.usage.value == "" )
   {
    alert( "Please provide your Vehicle Usage!" );
     document.myForm.usage.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
 if( document.myForm.vtype.value == 0 )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Vehicle Type!" );
     document.myForm.vtype.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
 if( document.myForm.vmodelno.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Model No!" );
     document.myForm.vmodelno.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
if( document.myForm.ftype.value == 0 )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Fuel Type!" );
      document.myForm.ftype.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
if( document.myForm.cmp.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Company Name!" );
     document.myForm.cmp.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
return( true );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear..

Answer (score 0):

on pressing enter form will get submitted.

instead you can call when focus is out for every input field. like:

```
$("#myfield").blur(function(){
     ----
});
```

This code work with Jquery